# New install of Docker and new Docker hub account both have too many pull requests

Tags: docker

I just installed Docker on a machine at work, but when I tried to test with

```
me@k1:~$ docker run hello-world
```

I got:

```
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: toomanyrequests: You have reached your pull rate limit. You may increase the limit by authenticating and upgrading: https://www.docker.com/increase-rate-limit.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

I then created a new docker hub account, logged into it and still got the same result:

```
me@k1:~$ sudo docker login --username=metoo
[sudo] password for me: 
Password: 
WARNING! Your password will be stored unencrypted in /root/.docker/config.json.
Configure a credential helper to remove this warning. See
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store

Login Succeeded
me@k1:~$ docker run hello-world
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: toomanyrequests: You have reached your pull rate limit. You may increase the limit by authenticating and upgrading: https://www.docker.com/increase-rate-limit.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

What should I do, other than waiting for 6 hours and hoping for the best.....